# how to resolve all git merge conflicts by choosing (d)eleted

Tags: git

I'm part way through a `git rebase` and I've got a bunch of files that are conflicting because they are changed in one branch and deleted in the other.

How do I resolve all such conflicts by choosing to delete?

Otherwise I've gotta press `d`, `return`, `d`, `return` 100s of times.

If there are any merge conflicts that need resolving using my mergetool, I'd still like to process these manually

`git rm --force .` seems to have no effect, it simply complains that the files "need merge"

Comment: `git checkout --ours` and/or `git checkout --theirs`, in combination with xargs, might well do the trick.

Comment: Are the deletes in the same branch or spread across both branches?

Comment: deletes are all in one, modified (only crlf whitespace, actually) in the other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *deletes are all in one, modified (only crlf whitespace, actually) in the other*

If there are whitespace-only changes in one branch, then

```
git rebase --ignore-whitespace <branch>...
```

should just ignore those changes. That may not be sufficient if there are other non-whitespace changes in the same commit.

Comment: ah didnt realise you could `--ignore-whitespace` on `rebase`, useful